# Different types of sacred fires from Vedic Period?

Tags: vedas, scripture, yajna, agni

While reading [This Web Site](http://www.eaglespace.com/spirit/gayatrig.php) , I have come across a description of various fires a grihastha (householder) was expected to keep in his house during Vedic period.

The  exact passage from  website is as below-:

**Every grihastha (householder) was expected to keep 5 or 3 sacred fires  (Five fires: Ahavaneeya, Dakshagni, Garhapatya, Sawta, Aavasadha ) in his house to perform Vedic rituals.**

So , I simply want to know more about these 5 types of sacred fires.

What was their purpose?

Which hymns from Vedas mentioned them?

Comment: I have read about three sacred fires (first three of your question). If you want then I can post answer on those three only.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani -: Yes you can :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Manusmriti](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu02.htm), the three fires Garhapatya, Dakshinagni and Ahavaniya are compared with father, mother and teacher respectively.

> पिता वै गार्हपत्योग्निर्माताग्निर्दक्षिणाः स्मृताः ।
>
> गुरुराहवनीयस्तु साग्नित्रेता गरीयसी ।। २३१ ।।
>
> 231. The father, forsooth, is stated to be the Garhapatya fire, the mother the Dakshinagni, but the teacher the Ahavaniya fire; this triad of fires is most venerable.
>
> त्रिष्वप्रमाद्यन्नेतेषु त्रील्लोलोकान् विजयेद्गृही ।
>
> दीप्यमानः स्ववपुषाः देववद्यिवि मोदते ।। २३२ ।।
>
> 232. He who neglects not those three, (even after he has become) a householder, will conquer the three worlds and, radiant in body like a god, he will enjoy bliss in heaven.

The glory of Ahavaniya and Garhapatya fire is mentioned in [Yajurved KANDA VI](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv06.htm).

> For this world the Garhapatya fire is piled up; for yonder world the Ahavaniya. If he were to cast it on-the Garhapatya fire, he would be rich in cattle in this world; if on the Ahavaniya, he would be rich in cattle in yonder world he casts it on both; verily he makes him rich in cattle in both worlds.

Also in [Yajurved KANDA I](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv01.htm)

> He falls away from this world who pays reverence to the Ahavaniya; he pays reverence to the Garhapatya; verily he rests on this world, and also he makes amends to the Garhapatya.

Comment: Also try to add sanskrit hymns mentioning  these fires.