# What are the five kind of offerings and vedic hymns Srimad Bhagavatham is referring to?

Tags: vedas, bhagavata-purana, yajur-veda, agni, hymn

In this verse from [Srimad Bhagavatham 4.7.41](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/7/41), Fire God is praising Narayana.

> The fire-god said: My dear Lord, I offer my respectful obeisances unto You because by Your favor I am as luminous as blazing fire and I accept the offerings mixed with butter and offered in sacrifice. **The five kinds of offerings according to the Yajur Veda are all Your different energies, and You are worshiped by five kinds of Vedic hymns.** Sacrifice means You, the Supreme Personality of Godhead.

I want to know,

1. What are the five kind of offerings that are given in Yajurveda?
2. What are the five kind of vedic hymns?

Comment: 5 offerings are the pancha pooja - gandham, pushpam, dhoopam, deepam and naivedyam each representing one of the 5 elements.

Comment: @moonstar dhoopam means incense sticks?

Comment: yes krishna shweta.

Comment: proves so thunderingly that Bhagavatam is of South Indian Brahmin origin (look at the five offerings).

Comment: @SK come to North India, they are offered in North indian temples too- it's Vedic not North Indian and South Indian.

Comment: "gandham", "Pushpam", "naivedyam" would make a typical present day North Indian burst out with laughter.  "dhoopam" and "deepam" are close enough to "dhoop" and "deep" but the "am" ending would sound "madrasi" to North Indian mastans.

Comment: @SK it's true we don't use those names, and use some persianized names but come to a North indian market during diwali- you'll find- colourful bottles of itr-gandham, a whole flower market, different kinds of natural powdered colours, some names may have changed due to influence of other religions but we are not that different.

Comment: @SK dhoopam , gandham, pushpam et cetera are sanskrit words. They are present in all Puraana be of Shiva, Vishnu, Devi, Ganesha or any other. Malayalam and other south languages kept their words close to Sanskrit, hence they still say Dhoopam, Gandham, et cetera. North started omitting the "m" part, hence they say Dhoop, Gandha, Pushp et cetera.

Comment: I dont think its panchopachara pooja

Comment: Yes it's not referring to the 5 upacharas.. @RakeshJoshi

Comment: @ rakeshjoshi, rickross - i have been misinformed then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Five kinds of offerings are referring to Vedic sacrifices or the sacred fires recommended for householders because they are said by Agni and he is sapeaking about Vedic sacrifices and offering made in the yajnas.

Following is the alternate translation of the verse according to Motilal Publications.

> Agni said:
>
> 41. I, whose flames are brightly enkindled by your light, bear the offerings soaked in ghee, in every good sacrifice. I bow to you who are sacrifice incarnate, and the protector of sacrifices—you who are fivefold in form and are duly worshipped by five hymns of the Yajurveda.

Various commentators (Sridhara Swamy, Vishvanatha Chakravarthi, Shuka Deva of Nimbarka Sampradaya, Giridhara) on Bhagavatam has opined that the five fold representation represent following five sacrifices.

- Agnihotra
- Darsha
- Purnamasa
- Chaturmasya
- Pashusoma

These are the sacrifices performed in the ancient period and are mentioned in the Vedas.

Veera Raghavacharaya gave the five forms as

- Dakshina
- Avahaniya
- Garhapatya
- Sabhya
- Avasathya

Above five are called five sacred fires which are kept by the house holders. These are mentioned in the Yajurveda as said in the Bhagavata Purana. Refer [Different types of sacred fires from Vedic Period?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14303/9125).

According to Vijaya dhwaja five fold form as:

- Yajna
- Yajna Purusha
- Yajnesha
- Yajna Bhavana
- Yajna bhuj

**The five hymns of the Yajurveda are:**

1. Ashravaya
2. Shraushat
3. Yaja
4. Ye Yajamahe
5. Vaushat

   From a [google groups discussion post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bvparishat/U3lvdMzlpG4),

   > In a yaj~na, the following happens (my humble prostrations to my R^igveda AchArya, shrii kR^iShNabhaTTa ghanapAThI who gave me, a worthless person, an opportunity to be an Agniidhra in a yaj~na and be able to mumble the following):
   >
   > 1. The adhvaryu (expert in yajurveda) asks the Agniidhra  (a person who is given the responsibility of driving away duShTa shaktis.) to look around (and ensure that there are no rAkShasas to disturb the yaj~na). For this, he utters the word: AshrAvaya or O shrAvaya (make us listen).
   > 2. The Agniidhra gives his consent by saying astu = may it be, shrauShaT = the word which removes duShTa shaktis. He has a wooden sword with him which he brings down ceremonially while pronouncing so.
   > 3. After listening to shrauShaT, the adhvaryu tells the hotaa (expert in R^igveda) to recite the shastra (shastra not shaastra. shastra is the recitation of R^igvedic mantras in a monotone ending with OM). the order given by the adhvaryu is "yaja" = may you call the devas.
   > 4. the hotaa accedes to the order and says, "ye yajAmahe" = here we invite.
   > 5. after the shastra is pronounced, he finishes it by saying OM and vauShaT. concurrent to hearing of vauShaT, the adhvaryu gives Ahuti to agni.

So, above are the five kinds of hymns recited in a yajna.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The 5 kind of hymns you said are recited during yajna, but given verse says "worshipped by five hymns of the Yajurveda". Are both same?

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Very interesting answer!

Comment: These look more of insividual mantras than a hymn....

Comment: @RakeshJoshi  Yes, they are mantrras only not hymns (if you take hymns as sukta). The problem is with English translation. The word used is Yajus in the Sanskrit shloka in the Bhagavatam.

Comment: Nice answer. [Which texts you read](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/573/277)?

Comment: @Pandya I am least interested in such discussions on meta. There are very serious problems on the site which should addressed. Spending time in updating huge list of texts every 3 days can be utilized in better discussion and moderation. This is used for knowing users personally. Lately, there has been mocking users of  this. It's better to link users to faq or some link rather than such discussions.

Comment: @User9125 what are those serious problems?

Comment: @Pandya Fanaticism, Bikeshed problem, serial downvoting, Sectarian fights, lack of proper policy for tagging, no proper moderation in chat. There are many. As a mod and participant on Meta, you should be knowing this.